# I need to drag down a formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Insert_Formula()

Dim NetPrice As String
NetPrice = "=I7*(100-N7)"
Worksheets(1).Range("O7").Formula = NetPrice

Dim StandardMargin As String
StandardMargin = "=O7-Q7-S7"
Worksheets(1).Range("T7").Formula = StandardMargin

Dim StandardMarginPercentage As String
StandardMarginPercentage = "=T7/O7"
Worksheets(1).Range("U7").Formula = StandardMarginPercentage

Dim GrossMargin As String
GrossMargin = "=T7-AB7"
Worksheets(1).Range("AC7").Formula = GrossMargin

Dim GrossMarginPercentage As String
GrossMarginPercentage = "=AD7/O7"
Worksheets(1).Range("AD7").Formula = GrossMarginPercentage

End Sub
```

This is my current formula and the problem is that i need the formula to be dragged down from the 7th row to the last row in the table for each column that has a formula but each column isn't right next to the other one.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `.AutoFill`, or write to `.FormulaR1C1` in `R1C1` format.

First you need to figure out the last row...

```
' Get the Last row
Dim LastRow as long
' You'll want to use a column that you know will have a value, to find the last row
LastRow = GetLastRow(9, Worksheets(1))        ' 9 = Column I
```

**GetLastRow Function**

```
Public Function GetLastRow(Optional Col As Integer = 1, Optional Sheet As Excel.Worksheet) As Long
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then Set Sheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    GetLastRow = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

**AutoFill**

```
Worksheets(1).Range("O7").AutoFill _
    Destination:=Worksheets(1).Range("O7:O"& LastRow), _
    Type:=xlFillDefault
```

**FormulaR1C1**

```
NetPrice = "=RC[-6]*(100-RC[-1])"
Worksheets(1).Range("O7:O"& LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = NetPrice
```

Comment: Or `FillDown` for a range (e.g. `Range("O7:O"& LastRow).FillDown`)

Comment: Hey! So the formula works but it drags down too far. There is information underneath where the drag down should stop and the formula goes into that data. It should stop at the first blank cell.

Comment: Instead of `GetLastRow()`, just use `Worksheets(1).Cells(7, Col).End(xlDown).Row`.  It will find the last cell with at value in it after row 7.  You should also make sure that Row 8 has a value or it will mess up and find the next table/list or the bottom of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through each row.

Here is an example for your first formula:

```
Sub Insert_Formula()
    Dim NetPrice As String
    For i = 7 to 17
        NetPrice = "=I" & i & "*(100-N" & i & ")"
        Worksheets(1).Range("O" & i).Formula = NetPrice
    Next i
End Sub
```